# cqlsh Connection refused

Tags: cassandra, connection, cqlsh

When ever you get a Cassandra cqlsh Connection error as follows:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: Found the solution. Please check the cqlsh DEFAULT_HOST points to the same ip as listen_address .

Answer (score 2):

You can also connect without using the IP address - just use the hostname:
cqlsh ‘hostname -I’

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, type `cqlsh <listen_address> [<port>]` if it is not set to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

Comment: Yes I tried your solution and it worked too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Cassandra 3.11.0, anytime I changed the address of rpc or listen address cqlsh wouldn't work. I had to add the same local ip to `seeds`

So after trial and error my cassandra.yml looked like:

```
class-name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
parameters: 
    -seeds: "192.168.0.30"

listen_adress: 192.168.0.30
rpc_address: 192.168.0.30
```

then running

```
cqlsh 192.168.0.30 9042
```

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Cassandra 3.11.1, I came across this problem. 
I also found if I ran

> service cassandra status

, there is a

> cassandra dead but pid file exists

problem. It indicates that the Cassandra service does not start
I checked the

> /var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log

and found this error:

> Exception encountered during startup...

.It is a bug and already reported. The original post link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173.

***The solution is to downgrade Cassandra to 3.0***

1. download Cassandra rpm

> curl -O
>   https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/30x/cassandra-3.0.15-1.noarch.rpm

or

> wget 
>   https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/redhat/30x/cassandra-3.0.15-1.noarch.rpm

2. rpm -ivh cassandra-3.0.15-1.noarch.rpm
3. service cassandra start
4. service cassandra status # check cassandra status, it should say

> cassandra (pid  1234) is running...

5. cqlsh #start cassandra

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

just check once already any Cassandra is running by
ps ax | grep cassandra

if yes kill that process using pid

kill pid

that worked for me